# Where are standard page layout buttons in the metadata?

Tags: page-layout, metadata

Where in the metadata I can find all page layouts that have the "Submit for Approval" button on them?

Doesn't seem to be in the page layout xml itself and I need to do a sweep for all page layouts that have this button on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard buttons work the other way around. The aren't specified if they *are* on the page layout, but if they are excluded from the layout.

So you will have to go through the xml files and see where `<excludeButtons>Submit</excludeButtons>` is not mentioned.

Have a look at the metadata api documentation, specifically the section on ***excludeButtons***.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm